# XSLT get nth node using dynamic number

Tags: xslt, dynamic, loops

I need to add CSS classes to each item output by an XSLT template.  The class values need to include the position of the node, which is fine, but the position needs to be written in words (classOne, classTwo etc) rather than a digits (class1, class2 etc).

The code I have almost works.  It outputs the position correctly as a number, but when I use that position to return the written version of the number it just picks the first one every time, so I always get a class of 'classOne'.  If I hard-code the number it works fine.

```
<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
<xsl:variable name="numbers" select="my.library:Split('One,Two,Three,Four,Five,Six,Seven,Eight',',')"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentPage/*[starts-with(name(), 'largeImage')]" mode="large" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="large">
  <xsl:variable name="index" select="substring(name(), 11)"/>
  <div class="class{$numbers/*[$index]}">item</div>
</xsl:template>
```

Can anyone see how I can get it to convert the $index value into the written equivalent?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a short and simple, *pure* XSLT 1.0 solution. No string-splitting and no extension functions at all. :)

Comment: Also added an XSLT 2.0 solution -- much more generic and much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<div class="class{$numbers/*[position() = $index]}">item</div>`. If that does not work then you need to show details of what kind of data your my.library:Split function returns.

Answer (score 1):

No string-splitting and extension functions are necessary to carry out the required processing:

**I. XSLT 1.0 Solution**

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:nums>
  <num>one</num>
  <num>two</num>
  <num>three</num>
  <num>four</num>
  <num>five</num>
  <num>six</num>
  <num>seven</num>
  <num>eight</num>
  <num>nine</num>
  <num>ten</num>
 </my:nums>

 <xsl:variable name="vNums" select="document('')/*/my:nums/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'largeImage')]">
   <xsl:variable name="vIndex">
     <xsl:number count="*[starts-with(name(), 'largeImage')]"
                 level="any"/>
   </xsl:variable>
   <div class="class{$vNums[position() = $vIndex]}">item</div>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (no source XML document was provided!):

```
<t>
 <largeImageA/>
 <largeImageB/>
 <largeImageC/>
 <largeImageD/>
 <largeImageE/>
 <largeImageF/>
 <largeImageG/>
 <largeImageH/>
 <largeImageI/>
 <largeImageJ/>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<div class="classone">item</div>
<div class="classtwo">item</div>
<div class="classthree">item</div>
<div class="classfour">item</div>
<div class="classfive">item</div>
<div class="classsix">item</div>
<div class="classseven">item</div>
<div class="classeight">item</div>
<div class="classnine">item</div>
<div class="classten">item</div>
```

**II. XSLT 2.0 Solution**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'largeImage')]">
   <xsl:variable name="vIndex">
     <xsl:number count="*[starts-with(name(), 'largeImage')]"
                 level="any" format="w"/>
   </xsl:variable>
   <div class="class{$vIndex}">item</div>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced**:

```
 <div class="classone">item</div>
 <div class="classtwo">item</div>
 <div class="classthree">item</div>
 <div class="classfour">item</div>
 <div class="classfive">item</div>
 <div class="classsix">item</div>
 <div class="classseven">item</div>
 <div class="classeight">item</div>
 <div class="classnine">item</div>
 <div class="classten">item</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat more verbose, but you could try something like:

```
  <xsl:template name="int2str">
    <xsl:param name="val" required="yes"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$val= 1">One</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$val= 2">Two</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$val= 3">Three</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$val= 4">Four</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$val= 5">Five</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$val= 6">Six</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$val= 7">Seven</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$val= 8">Eight</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

you can call it with:

```
<xsl:call-template name="int2str">
  <xsl:with-param name="val" select="$index"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: That wouldn't work since I have no idea how many request/response elements I have (other than that I have the same number of requests and responses)